# How is the information displayed by "top" ordered by default?

Tags: top

Been looking at `top` command as I'm new to Linux, but I can't see any correlations on how the displayed information is sorted. Can anyone sched any light on that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`top` will display first the most demanding processes (highest %CPU) and then the others by decreasing %CPU.

Answer (score 0):

The display starts *by default* sorted (descending) on the `%CPU` column.

However, the `<` and `>` keys select other columns: for example, a single `>` makes it sort on `%MEM` at the next refresh. The `R` key reverses the order: for example, 8 `<` plus `R` keeps the whole list in `PID` number order. The `x` key toggles highlighting of the complete column which is currently being sorted.

The `f` command opens up a menu where you can rearrange the whole panel as much as you wish, adding and hiding columns, etc. There are (around) 53 fields (columns) available for display: for example `OOMs  --  Out of Memory Score`.

`info top` should give you 2000 lines of detail, or try `https://linux.die.net/man/1/top`.